# need abolute path of every running process using the registsry vb.net

Tags: process

I'm writing a "set priority" app and I need to ask a couple of things. I can get a list of every running process, and I want to be able to change their priority. Do I need to know the absolute path of the process to be able to do that?

I've read that you can get the full path to a process with the registry, but not sure of that. If anyone can help me out, I sure would appreciate it.

Comment: When you look at the documentation for [SetPriorityClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), what is it expecting you to provide? Does it look like it needs the full path? And what does the registry have to do with running processes?

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for the reply. I looked at the SetPriorityClass and it's in c#. I do vb.net so it's a little tough for me to figure out. I'm using a listview to load up all running process. I'm not sure if I need to get the path. I just thought I might. can I get or set priority from the apps in the listview without needing the path? I'm a bit new at vb.net, but what I want is to be able to get the priority and set the priority. Thanks for being patient :)

Comment: What you need is a *process handle* (which it clearly says in the link I posted above, whether you're using C#, VB.Net, C++, or any other language). With all due respect, if you're not able to understand what that is, you probably shouldn't be mucking around with changing process priorities. :-) I also don't see any tag for a specific language on your question, and there's no mention of a language in the text you provided either. I was able to figure out you were asking about Windows only because you mentioned the registry (which isn't even relevant). Did you search here at all?

Comment: I was a C++ programmer for 20+ years. I've been retired for a long time and just now getting into .net...So yes, I know what a handle is :) Maybe I should take a better look at the link you gave me. And sorry about the tags. Many tags I try say that I can't use it unless I have "n" amount of posts. Let me look at the link and I'll get right back to you. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Ok, I'm guilty of not looking good at the code in the link you sent. Sorry about that... my fault. So thank you for helping. You have given me all I need to know for what I was wanting to do. THANKS!